# Securing connection string in .Net app.config files

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

In my .net application version 4.0, we are displaying both the userID and password in the connection string of app config file. I wanted to know how to secure the ID n Password - which can be implemented  with minimal effort.

```
<db:provider id="dbProvider" provider="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data  Source=AdventureWorks;Initial Catalog=userDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=XXXXX"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460911/encrypting-the-connection-string-in-web-config-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Short answer is that you don't. You use windows integrated security instead.

Comment: @steve Integrated security isn't always available, what if the SQL Server is on another domain or in Azure cloud for example?

Answer (score 0):

You could save your user and password encrypted as another settings in app.config. 
To use it, decrypt user and password and replace your connection string.

```
string connString = string.Format("Data Source=AdventureWorks;Initial Catalog=userDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={0};Password={1}", user, passord);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for encryption of web.config using aspnet_regiis.exe commandline. Something like [aspnet-regiis-exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730114/how-to-properly-encrypt-my-web-config-using-aspnet-regiis-exe)

Word of warning: since it's aspnet_regiis, it expects to be dealing with a web.config file - copy your app.config to a location and call it web.config, encrypt your sections, and copy those encrypted sections back into your own app.config.